# Lilypad sends corrupted data on Serial

Tags: serial

I have an Arduino Lilypad with this simple code where I try to write a simple message to the serial console. The baud rate is set to 9600 both in the code as well as in the serial console and I'm using the [FTDI UART tool](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10275).
However, the output I'm receiving is corrupted and I'm not sure what could be the cause. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(3000);
  Serial.write("Hello World");
}
```

[image]

Arduino is connected to the FTDI tool as shown here [image]

Comment: @jsotola I have it connected as shown on the picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/axOsO.png

Comment: @jsotola updated, but that doesn't really answer my question 

Comment: Just as an experiment, try changing the code to make the serial port 4800 and if that doesn't work, try 119200. Alternatively, change the speed in the Terminal Monitor window to double or halve the speed.

Comment: I say that because it looks like the baud rate is wrong. Don't change both settings at once.

Comment: Does the LED blink with the 3-second delay?

Comment: @NickGammon changing the baud rate to 4800 while keeping 9600 in the terminal solved this. Now I can see properly written "Hello World" in the console. Can you post it as an answer here and I'll mark it as solved? Also, could you please explain why is that? Thanks a lot

Comment: He shouldn't. The answer should follow from the question. What he offered you was perfectly good diagnostic advice. At least he realized that and put it in a comment this time. What you've put in your comment is information that can be integrated into the question. A *real* answer as to why (or "what" following from what you asked) is still unknown.

Comment: What we have now is just an unexplained work-around. We still need to find out the underling reason, _why_ you need different baudrates for your Lilypad and the PC. Is it possible that the IDE thinks that the Lilypad has a 16 MHz clock?

Comment: @timemage My answer (now posted) **did** follow from the question. What else would it follow from?

Comment: All three Lilypad boards are 8 Mhz. Of the two non-USB versions that take an FTDI style header, only the matching board definition will upload successfully because they have different bootloader baud rates. As the busybee said, what you have is a workaround. The actual cause and potential problem is still there. Incorrect fuses, wrong bootloader, boards.txt has been altered, core altered to set CLKPR, who knows? And we and future readers not going to know as things stand. I appreciate that you're happy to see your message printing though.

Comment: @timemage I agree we haven't solved the underlying problem, but without knowing exactly what board they selected, whether or not boards.txt was altered, the fuses on the Lilypad, etc. then the solution remains as a work-around. However quite possibly no-one else will have this exact problem. Even if they did, how would we know for sure it was the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the wrong baud rate. That often results in garbage characters. You said in a comment that halving the baud rate on the Arduino end seemed to synchronize the baud rates, and you could see proper characters.

I'm a bit puzzled by that because you were evidently able to upload the sketch in the first place. Therefore the baud rate was correct during the uploading process.

Looking in the file `boards.txt` which you should find somewhere in your Arduino installation, there appear to be a number of Lilypad variants. Perhaps you inadvertently chose the wrong one in the "Board" menu in the IDE?

It looks like the correct baud rate was used for the uploading, but the code generated by the compiler (because of settings passed by the IDE) thought that the board was running at half the speed it actually was (so it set the baud rate clocks to run faster), so by reducing the baud rate in the Serial.begin they became in sync.

You could just live with the difference, or try experimenting with choosing different Lilypad board types.

If the baud rate is wrong, probably the delays will be wrong too, whether or not that matters is up to you.